# xcode crashing for using Key I never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So my application is crashing here:

```
- (void)showMenu
{
MenuViewController *menuVC = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
NSLog(@"between the two things");
[self.navigationController pushViewController:menuVC animated:YES];
 NSLog(@"after it was pushed");
}
```

The first NSLog works, but the second doesn't. I have an identical showSettings function so the error is supposedly in MenuViewController. The error I am getting says:

```
2013-09-22 02:12:05.308 Mhacks[13947:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception'
NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MenuViewController 0xc3c6600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key rearTableView.']

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c98012 0x10d5e7e 0x1d20fb1 0xb81e41 0xb035f8 0xb030e7 0xb2db58 0x237019 0x10e9663 0x1c9345a 0x235b1c 0xfa7e7 0xfadc8 0x24928e 0xfaff8 0xfb232 0xfb4da 0x1128e5 0x1129cb 0x112c76 0x112d71 0x11389b 0x113e93 0x113a88 0x28c3 0x10e9705 0x1d2c0 0x1d258 0xde021 0xde57f 0xdd6e8 0x4ccef 0x4cf02 0x2ad4a 0x1c698 0x1bf3df9 0x1bf3ad0 0x1c0dbf5 0x1c0d962 0x1c3ebb6 0x1c3df44 0x1c3de1b 0x1bf27e3 0x1bf2668 0x19ffc 0x1d0d 0x1c35 0x1)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I have searched the project and "rearTableView" isn't used anywhere (I used it at some point but I deleted that class and everything that had to do with it)

I've also Cleaned my project multiple times. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: I faced the same problem and I solved it by this: try to clean your project using the keys: (cmd + shift + option + k) not product > clean. If this doesn't work for you, close the xcode and open it again.

Comment: Check if the view outlets in properly set to the files owner in MenuViewController.xib

Comment: @thatzprem I don't have a xib file for menuviewcontroller yet. I'm just trying to get it to look like a basic tableview right now and it keeps crashing

Answer (score 1):

You likely still have a reference to `rearTableView` in a nib. Open the relevant nib, select File's Owner, and check the Connections inspector. If you see rearTableView there, remove it with the x button.

Comment: great guess but not it - I only have one xib file and it is for settingsviewcontroller and doesn't reference reartableview :/